# Reading file data into a struct and then sorting said data

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct, file-read

My assignment is to read data in from a txt file and then sort it into an array. I've the basis of the code setup and I'm getting issues from the command line that don't necessarily recognize or are even for.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct info{
  int number;
  string name;
  double salary;
};
int main() {
    ifstream file("input.txt");
    string st;
    int i = 0, j, swaps = 1,x;
    info items[10];
    file.open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Prog-1/input.txt");
    if(!file){
      cerr << "Unable to open file datafile.txt" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    while (file >> x){
      //  echo input
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
          cout << items[i].number << items[i].name << items[i].salary << endl;
        }
        int swaps = 1;
        while(swaps == 1){
          swaps = 0;
          for(j = 0; j < i-1; j++){
            if(items[j].name > items[j+1].name)
              swap(items[j], items[j+1]);
              swaps = 1;
          }
        }
        //  echo input
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
          cout << items[i].number << items[i].name << items[i].salary << endl;
        }
        while(swaps = -1){
          swaps = 0;
          for(j = 0; j < i-1; j++){
            if(items[j].salary < items[j+1].salary)
              swap(items[j], items[j+1]);
              swaps = 1;
          }
        }
    }
    file.close();
  }
```

Then here is what is showing up in my console:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator!() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `std::cerr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator bool() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `std::cout'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(double)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to `std::cout'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x297): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x2e3): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(double)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x2f4): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x3bf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::close()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x3ee): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ifstream()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x435): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x442): undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ifstream()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x467): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text+0x488): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text$_ZN4infoC1Ev[__ZN4infoC1Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text$_ZN4infoD1Ev[__ZN4infoD1Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text$_ZStgtIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEbRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EESA_[__ZStgtIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEbRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EESA_]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text$_ZN4infoC1EOS_[__ZN4infoC1EOS_]+0x25): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.text$_ZN4infoaSEOS_[__ZN4infoaSEOS_]+0x25): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIDnsGB.o:hw7.cpp:(.eh_frame$_ZStgtIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEbRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EESA_+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, what I'm not including or what I'm not implementing.

Comment: try to replace this: `ifstream file("input.txt");` with this: `ifstream file("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Prog-1/input.txt");`. and delete this line: `file.open(C:/Users/user/Desktop/Prog-1/input.txt)`

Comment: @DynamicSquid Good advice but not related to the problem

Comment: J.Flores: Show the command line you use to compile the program.

Answer (score 1):

You're compiling this code using a C-language compiler. Not a C++ one. That's why you can't find a reference to all the C++ functions you used. The code is correct but your project setup is wrong. Create a new C++ project on the IDE you're using and paste your code and it will work fine.

**EDIT**

Ted Lyngmo mentioned in the comments that if it was compiled using `gcc` it would fail at the compilation stage not the linking stage. But I was still able to reproduce the error after compiling the code with `gcc` and it turned out that the reason why `gcc` could compile the code and fail to link it is because of the file extension. It was `.cpp`. The answer is the same. Compile your code using the proper compiler, which is `g++`.

Comment: If it is compiled as C code it would probably fail to compile but this fails in the linking phase.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, try it yourself. C code fails at the linking stage not compiling stage.

Comment: I don't need to try it myself. Even if the C compiler would find the file `iostream` at `#include <iostream>` if can't possibly compile what's in it. Also, there are a lot of things in OP:s program that can't be compiled as C. [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/x47a47)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I got the point. But for no obvious reason, I managed to reproduce the error he got after compiling his code with `gcc` instead of `g++`. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with a 9.3 version of gcc. I will look it up but that's what happened with me. The same exact error he got could be produced (at least on my machine) using `gcc`.

Comment: Yes, well, it's then still compiled as a C++ program (the filename probably ends with `.cpp`), but if you use `gcc` it won't include the necessary C++ libraries, so the answer is to use `g++` not `gcc`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're correct. I edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Another option is to add the missing C++ library: `gcc foo.cpp -lstdc++` should work too.